# Oracle DB - why would execution plan of this seeming wrong query changed suddenly? Not sure if the correct version can fix the plan

Tags: java, oracle, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Long version:
I have a large table which I want to execute a query like:

```sql
-- original
select IH.* from ITEM_HISTORY IH 
    join ITEM_PACKAGE IP on IP.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME 
    where IP.OPERATOR_ID = ? 
    and (
        IH.OPERATION != 'CHANGE_OWNER' OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE
    ) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != 'NOT_APPLICABLE' 
    and IH.EVENT_DATE >= ? and IH.EVENT_DATE < ?
    and ROWNUM <= 500000
    order by IH.EVENT_DATE
```

which is a native query defined in `@NamedNativeQuery` of JPA.
Each row represents a change event happened to an item. There are so many operators who can modify items, so `ITEM_HISTORY` table is a huge table which oftentimes causes us trouble. It contains millions of records and often times out.

Recently, we have an incident where when production pods running this query, Oracle suddenly changed the execution plan to a bad one, going a less optimized "route", and slowed down the pods, finally leads to application non responsiveness. We had to restart the pod to make it back to normal. Clients are unhappy and DB team just fixed the execution plan to the usual, better one. But they ask us, as DEV, what can be done at application side.

At first sight, I think: ah, this is wrong, because in Oracle database, we should use "inline view" or `fetch first X rows`, because in this way, Oracle database knows how to optimize it with stopkey sort or window sort pushed rank, so, this is an easy one!(I learned these from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhOVF82KY7E) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/post/on-rownum-and-limiting-results))

So I changed it to:

```sql
-- version 1
select * from (
    select IH.* from ITEM_HISTORY IH 
        join ITEM_PACKAGE IP on IP.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME 
        where IP.OPERATOR_ID = ? 
        and (
            IH.OPERATION != 'CHANGE_OWNER' OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE
        ) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != 'NOT_APPLICABLE' 
        and IH.EVENT_DATE >= ? and IH.EVENT_DATE < ?
        order by IH.EVENT_DATE
) where ROWNUM <= 500000
```

And, this one:

```sql
-- version 2
select IH.* from ITEM_HISTORY IH 
    join ITEM_PACKAGE IP on IP.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME 
    where IP.OPERATOR_ID = ? 
    and (
        IH.OPERATION != 'CHANGE_OWNER' OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE
    ) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != 'NOT_APPLICABLE' 
    and IH.EVENT_DATE >= ? and IH.EVENT_DATE < ?
    and ROWNUM <= 500000
    order by IH.EVENT_DATE
    fetch first 500000 rows only;
```

But, I don't find much performance improvement. I see version 1 is even slower than original, and version 2 is faster, but the execution plans shows the same cost.
(The test is done in staging env, where the range filter will fetch 400K rows)

```sql
-- original 21789 ms / 34598 ms
explain plan for
select * from ITEM_HISTORY IH 
join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME
where OPERATOR_ID = '88000001' and (IH.OPERATION != 'CHANGE_OWNER' OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) 
and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != 'NOT_APPLICABLE'
and IH.EVENT_DATE >= TO_DATE('2018/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and IH.EVENT_DATE < TO_DATE('2020/05/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
and rownum < 500000
order by IH.EVENT_DATE;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DIP.AY(NULL));
-- Plan hash.value: 1529757427
--  
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | Id  | Operation                   | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempP.| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                      | 66280 |    29M|       |   133K  (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
-- |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY              |                      | 66280 |    29M|    34M|   133K  (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
-- |*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY             |                      |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
-- |*  3 |    hash.JOIN                |                      | 66280 |    29M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
-- |*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL       | PACKAGE              |   545 |   120K|       |    25   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
-- |   5 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                      |   287K|    64M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |    44 |    65 |
-- |*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL      | ITEM_HISTORY         |   287K|    64M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |    44 |    65 |
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  
-- Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
-- ---------------------------------------------------
--  
--    2 - filter(ROWNUM<500000)
--    3 - access("P"."PACKAGE_NAME"="IH"."PACKAGE_NAME")
--    4 - filter("P"."OPERATOR_ID"='88000001')
--    6 - filter("IH"."EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION"<>'NOT_APPLICABLE' AND ("IH"."OPERATION"<>'CHANGE_OWNER' OR 
--               "IH"."EVENT_DATE"="IH"."INSTALLATION_DATE"))
--  
-- Note
-- -----
--    - this is an adaptive plan

-- final query(new) 33342 ms / 26423 ms
select * from (
    select * from ITEM_HISTORY IH 
    join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME
    where OPERATOR_ID = '88000001' and (IH.OPERATION != 'CHANGE_OWNER' OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) 
    and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != 'NOT_APPLICABLE'
    and IH.EVENT_DATE >= TO_DATE('2018/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and IH.EVENT_DATE < TO_DATE('2020/05/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
    order by IH.EVENT_DATE
) where rownum < 500000;
SELECT *   FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DIP.AY(NULL));
-- Plan hash.value: 3376840570
--  
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | Id  | Operation                    | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempP.| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                      | 66280 |   412M|       |   133K  (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
-- |*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |                      |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
-- |   2 |   VIEW                       |                      | 66280 |   412M|       |   133K  (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
-- |*  3 |    SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY     |                      | 66280 |    29M|    34M|   133K  (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
-- |*  4 |     hash.JOIN                |                      | 66280 |    29M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
-- |*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL       | PACKAGE |   545 |   120K|       |    25   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
-- |   6 |      PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                      |   287K|    64M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |    44 |    65 |
-- |*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL      | ITEM_HISTORY |   287K|    64M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |    44 |    65 |
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  
-- Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
-- ---------------------------------------------------
--  
--    1 - filter(ROWNUM<500000)
--    3 - filter(ROWNUM<500000)
--    4 - access("P"."PACKAGE_NAME"="IH"."PACKAGE_NAME")
--    5 - filter("P"."OPERATOR_ID"='88000001')
--    7 - filter("IH"."EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION"<>'NOT_APPLICABLE' AND ("IH"."OPERATION"<>'CHANGE_OWNER' OR 
--               "IH"."EVENT_DATE"="IH"."INSTALLATION_DATE"))


-- final query 2(fetch X rows only) 19662 ms / 19437 ms 
explain plan for
    select * from ITEM_HISTORY IH 
    join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME
    where OPERATOR_ID = '88000001' and (IH.OPERATION != 'CHANGE_OWNER' OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) 
    and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != 'NOT_APPLICABLE'
    and IH.EVENT_DATE >= TO_DATE('2018/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and IH.EVENT_DATE < TO_DATE('2020/05/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
    order by IH.EVENT_DATE
fetch first 500000 rows only;
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DIP.AY(NULL));
--Plan hash.value: 3207167953
-- 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--| Id  | Operation                   | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempP.| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                      |   500K|  3120M|       |   133K  (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
--|*  1 |  VIEW                       |                      |   500K|  3120M|       |   133K  (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
--|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUIH.D RANK   |                      | 66280 |    29M|    34M|   133K  (1)| 00:00:06 |       |       |
--|*  3 |    hash.JOIN                |                      | 66280 |    29M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |
--|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL       | PACKAGE              |   545 |   120K|       |    25   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
--|   5 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|                      |   287K|    64M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |    44 |    65 |
--|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL      | ITEM_HISTORY         |   287K|    64M|       |   126K  (1)| 00:00:05 |    44 |    65 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
--Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------
-- 
--   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_004"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=500000)
--   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "IH"."EVENT_DATE")<=500000)
--   3 - access("P"."PACKAGE_NAME"="IH"."PACKAGE_NAME")
--   4 - filter("P"."OPERATOR_ID"='88000001')
--   6 - filter("IH"."EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION"<>'NOT_APPLICABLE' AND ("IH"."OPERATION"<>'CHANGE_OWNER' OR 
--              "IH"."EVENT_DATE"="IH"."INSTALLATION_DATE"))
```

So, the question:

- At last, will the version 2 solve the execution changed to bad one problem? I am not sure.
  <strike>- Does it have to do with the rows fetched? I suspect that most of the time, the rows are so few, that original version, even wrong, have covered all rows, so it's actually correct, as when X < 500K, original will fetch all and sort, which gives correct results. But at the time of incident the rows number became bigger, and the plan changed. But I am not DBA and I am not sure</strike> DBA said that this query always returns almost 500K records indeed, so we always have a lot of rows to fetch.
- What can cause an execution plan change, and then slow down the Oracle DB, and then leads to application crash? I don't get it.

EDIT:
I managed to get the execution plans used during the incident. The first one and second one are usually used. The bad one is the third one. Timestamp 1 and 2 are several days before incident time. Timestamp 3 is incident time.

| DBID | SQL_ID | PLAN_HASH_VALUE | ID | OPERATION | OPTIONS | OBJECT_NODE | OBJECT# | OBJECT_OWNER | OBJECT_NAME | OBJECT_ALIAS | OBJECT_TYPE | OPTIMIZER | PARENT_ID | DEPTH | POSITION | SEARCH_COLUMNS | COST | CARDINALITY | BYTES | OTHER_TAG | PARTITION_START | PARTITION_STOP | PARTITION_ID | OTHER | DISTRIBUTION | CPU_COST | IO_COST | TEMP_SPACE | ACCESS_PREDICATES | FILTER_PREDICATES | PROJECTION | TIME | QBLOCK_NAME | REMARKS | TIMESTAMP | OTHER_XML | CON_DBID | CON_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ALL_ROWS |  | 0 | 111 | 0 | 111 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 1 | SORT | ORDER BY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 111 | 30 | 8220 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 40060576 | 110 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 2 | COUNT | STOPKEY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 3 | FILTER |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 4 | HASH JOIN |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 110 | 30 | 8220 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 5581756 | 110 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 5 | TABLE ACCESS | FULL |  | 175586 | MY_APP | PACKAGE | SP@SEL$1 | TABLE |  | 4 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 105 | 27 | 945 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4897690 | 105 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 6 | PARTITION RANGE | ITERATOR |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 426 | 101814 |  | KEY | KEY | 6 |  |  | 37416 | 5 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 7 | TABLE ACCESS | BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED |  | 174723 | MY_APP | ITEM_HISTORY | SH@SEL$1 | TABLE |  | 6 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 426 | 101814 |  | KEY | KEY | 6 |  |  | 37416 | 5 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash1 | 8 | INDEX | RANGE SCAN |  | 174726 | MY_APP | IX_ITEM_HISTORY_EVENTD | SH@SEL$1 | INDEX |  | 7 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |  |  | KEY | KEY | 6 |  |  | 21764 | 3 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp1 |  | random_number | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ALL_ROWS |  | 0 | 6 | 0 | 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2021-09-01 23:00:00 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 1 | COUNT | STOPKEY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 2 | FILTER |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 3 | NESTED LOOPS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 274 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 47177 | 6 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 4 | NESTED LOOPS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 274 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 47177 | 6 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 5 | PARTITION RANGE | ITERATOR |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 239 |  | KEY | KEY | 5 |  |  | 37416 | 5 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 6 | TABLE ACCESS | BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID |  | 174723 | MY_APP | ITEM_HISTORY | SH@SEL$1 | TABLE |  | 5 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 239 |  | KEY | KEY | 5 |  |  | 37416 | 5 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 7 | INDEX | RANGE SCAN |  | 174726 | MY_APP | IX_ITEM_HISTORY_EVENTD | SH@SEL$1 | INDEX |  | 6 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |  |  | KEY | KEY | 5 |  |  | 21764 | 3 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 8 | INDEX | UNIQUE SCAN |  | 175998 | MY_APP | UK_PACKAGE_NAME | SP@SEL$1 | INDEX (UNIQUE) |  | 4 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1900 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash2 | 9 | TABLE ACCESS | BY INDEX ROWID |  | 175586 | MY_APP | PACKAGE | SP@SEL$1 | TABLE |  | 3 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 35 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 9761 | 1 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp2 |  | random_number | 0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | HINT: ALL_ROWS |  | 0 | 25551 | 0 | 25551 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 1 | SORT | ORDER BY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 25551 | 391 | 111044 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1414967960 | 25510 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 2 | COUNT | STOPKEY |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 3 | PX COORDINATOR |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 4 | PX SEND | QC (RANDOM) | :Q1001 |  | SYS | :TQ10001 |  |  |  | 3 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 25550 | 391 | 111044 | PARALLEL_TO_SERIAL |  |  |  |  | QC (RANDOM) | 1376651756 | 25510 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 5 | COUNT | STOPKEY | :Q1001 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 5 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  | PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 6 | FILTER |  | :Q1001 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 5 | 6 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  | PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 7 | HASH JOIN |  | :Q1001 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 6 | 7 | 1 | 0 | 25550 | 391 | 111044 | PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT |  |  |  |  |  | 1376651756 | 25510 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 8 | JOIN FILTER | CREATE | :Q1001 |  | SYS | :BF0000 |  |  |  | 7 | 8 | 1 | 0 | 105 | 21 | 735 | PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT |  |  |  |  |  | 4938130 | 105 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 9 | PX RECEIVE |  | :Q1001 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 105 | 21 | 735 | PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT |  |  |  |  |  | 4938130 | 105 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 10 | PX SEND | BROADCAST | :Q1000 |  | SYS | :TQ10000 |  |  |  | 9 | 10 | 1 | 0 | 105 | 21 | 735 | PARALLEL_FROM_SERIAL |  |  |  |  | BROADCAST | 4938130 | 105 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 11 | PX SELECTOR |  | :Q1000 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 10 | 11 | 1 | 0 |  |  |  | SINGLE_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 12 | TABLE ACCESS | FULL | :Q1000 | 175586 | MY_APP | PACKAGE | SP@SEL$1 | TABLE |  | 11 | 12 | 1 | 0 | 105 | 21 | 735 | SINGLE_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT |  |  |  |  |  | 4938130 | 105 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 13 | JOIN FILTER | USE | :Q1001 |  | SYS | :BF0000 |  |  |  | 7 | 8 | 2 | 0 | 25445 | 14946 | 3721554 | PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT |  |  |  |  |  | 1370926276 | 25405 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 14 | PX BLOCK | ITERATOR | :Q1001 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 13 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 25445 | 14946 | 3721554 | PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_CHILD | KEY | KEY | 14 |  |  | 1370926276 | 25405 |  |  |  |  | 1 |  |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |
| random_number | random_id | hash3 | 15 | TABLE ACCESS | FULL | :Q1001 | 174723 | MY_APP | ITEM_HISTORY | SH@SEL$1 | TABLE |  | 14 | 10 | 1 | 0 | 25445 | 14946 | 3721554 | PARALLEL_COMBINED_WITH_PARENT | KEY | KEY | 14 |  |  | 1370926276 | 25405 |  |  |  |  | 1 | SEL$58A6D7F6 |  | timestamp3 |  | random_number | 0 |

Comment: if the elapsed time is more or less the same, the problem is not the `fetching` phase, but the `execution` phase of the sql statement. You are using adaptive plans, so the CBO is changing plans if it considers is better. I know sometimes it doesn't , but normally it is related to statistics collection. How often are you collecting statistics in the partitioned table ? and which granularity are you using ? Do you have indexes in the partitioned table ?

Comment: It appears that `item_history` is partitioned.  What is the partition key?  `event_date`?  How selective is `operator_id` in `package`?  Is that defined as a `varchar2` rather than a `number`?  Because your query is comparing it to a number which would prevent the optimizer from using an index on `operator_id` like I'd expect you'd want to.  I'd expect that you'd want `package_name` indexed as well since I assume that would be reasonably selective.  Are any of the other predicates selective?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I think the collection is daily, but I don't know about granularity. The index over the event_date exists.

Comment: @JustinCave `OPERATOR_ID` is String in Java, in table is varchar(32), is a FK to another table. `package_name` is not indexed, only has an unique constraint.

Comment: I have updated the plans used before and during the incident.

Comment: the third plan contains a PARALLEL execution, that is why you see entries containing the words PX COORDINATOR and PX SEND. Either you run the query once with parallel or your DBA has created a SQL Profile with parallelism.

Comment: If `operator_id` is a `varchar2` in the database and is being bound as a String in Java, the examples you posted where you were comparing it to a number are problematic because it prevents Oracle from using the index on `package` that the second plan appears to be using.

Comment: @JustinCave sorry, I checked the report from DBA, the first param is VARCHAR, not number. The SQL is my test, not the real one. I ran the queries again with string param in SQL and updated the question, but the time taken seems not changed much.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez The report is taken from production, and I think at that time, Oracle changed the plan itself, without human interference. The production always runs fine and fulfills its task, so no one had any reason to change anything.

Comment: @WesternGun, Oracle never does that. The third one is because a SQL Profile for this SQL ID was generated with parellellism. That might happen automatically if your DBA has enabled auto sql profile generation.

Comment: @WesternGun, if your Java Application is using `bind variables` a possibility is that the adaptive plan is suffering from `bind peeking`.  Check this with your dba. I would advice to create a SQL Plan Baseline for the sqlid / plan hash you say it works fine. Thereby Oracle will use always that plan

Comment: Thanks @RobertoHernandez, I am not DBA but let me try to summarize: 1, ask our DBA to disable "Auto SQL profile generation", 2, create a "SQL plan baseline" for the good execution plan, right? So, what command/query should the DBA run? Thanks.

Comment: @WesternGun, I will put that in the answer section

Comment: @RobertoHernandez thanks. Do you think it's better to change the query to using `fetch first 500000 rows only` or not? I mean, should I touch the code, wait for another week, and see which is the new plan in use, is it better, or just don't touch the code, let DBA do their work?

Comment: I think your wrong execution was due to the SQL Profile ( the one with parallel workers ). I would insist for your DBA to avoid auto sql profile generation altogether. I don't think you have a problem in fetching, but in execution. Nevertheless, if your bind peeking issue might lead to the optimizer to use different plans, Baselines are always the way to go, as you assure the same plan will always be used no matter what values are in the bind variables. I also believe the indexes are not used because the selectivity is not enough to compensate, thus Oracle is using full scan

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the comment's section, let me summarize:

- If one statement runs in parallel with the same `sql_id`, then it is clear that either you run the statement, or a SQL Profile was generated as recommendation to improve the execution using parallel query.
- That can only happen automatically when SQL Profiles are automatically accepted.
- My advice: That is a really bad practice. SQL Profiles should not be automatically accepted. They should be reviewed by the DBAS, and only accepted after consideration and proper analysis.

A normal scenario is the so called `bind peeking` issue. I am not going to explain it, you have a lot of articles in Internet about it. One way to fix it is to create a `sql plan baseline`.

**How to create a SQL Plan Baseline ?**

From Cache

Step 1

Manual plan loading can be used in conjunction with, or as an alternative to automatic plan capture. The load operations are performed using the `DBMS_SPM` package, which allows SQL plan baselines to be loaded from SQL tuning sets or from specific SQL statements in the cursor cache. Manually loaded statements are flagged as accepted by default. If a SQL plan baseline is present for a SQL statement, the plan is added to the baseline, otherwise a new baseline is created.

```
DECLARE
  l_plans_loaded  PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  l_plans_loaded := DBMS_SPM.load_plans_from_sqlset(
    sqlset_name => 'my_sqlset');
END;
/

DECLARE
  l_plans_loaded  PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  l_plans_loaded := DBMS_SPM.load_plans_from_cursor_cache(
    sql_id => 'yoursqlid', plan_hash_value => 'yourplanhasvalue');
END;
/
```

The return value of the `LOAD_PLANS_FROM_SQLSET` and `LOAD_PLANS_FROM_CURSOR_CACHE` functions indicates the number of plan loaded by the function call.

```
SELECT sql_handle, plan_name, enabled, accepted FROM   dba_sql_plan_baselines
```

Verify that the plan is accepted and enabled.

If the `sql_id` and `plan_hash_value` are not longer in memory, you would need to use AWR for creating the baseline. If that is the case, here you have a very good guide step by step

[Sql Baseline using AWR](https://dbtechno.blogspot.com/2020/06/12c-sql-baseline-loading-sql-plan-from.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. We have 2 pods/instances of the same application, can the parallelism be due to that? But normally we don't see it... it's so strange.

Comment: No, the parallel execution is coming from the database, not from the PODs. I had a similar problem in my scenario with Azure Kubernetes , and it was because someone activate auto sql profile generation. Your PODs have nothing to do with the issue

Comment: @WesternGun, I would appreciate if you upvote the answer, and if it finally solves your issue accept it. Thank you

Comment: I should thank you for your time and effort dedicated to answering my question. It's a pity that I cannot accept it right away, as I am on Java side and this must be DBA's tasks to actually implement your solution; it is a little bit delicate now, as I got an answer not about code, but about DB, and I cannot test it myself. But thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: @WesternGun, you're very welcome. Come back here if any other issue arise. Happy to have helped you ;)

Comment: I asked DBA and they told me that `ACCEPT_SQL_PROFILES` is false. He uses this query: `select TASK_NAME,PARAMETER_NAME,PARAMETER_VALUE,DESCRIPTION from dba_ADVISOR_parameters where task_name='SYS_AUTO_SQL_TUNING_TASK' and parameter_name='ACCEPT_SQL_PROFILES'`

Comment: well, that is quite odd. The only way a statement with same SQLID can generate a execution plan using Parallel execution is by using an accepted profile. Can you ask for this and post in the question : `select * from dbms_xplan(display_cursor('yoursqlid'))` . That will give you the three plans that should be in memory associated to each child cursor of the statement, incliuding the one with the parallel execution

Comment: Check it here: https://pastebin.com/ikLHeDZ9, expires in one day

Comment: @WesternGun. For the plans you might see that some of the executions were running in parallel. The reason might be ( besides an auto sql profile ) that: 1.the tables have a parallel degree definition, although unlikely. 2. A session forcing parallel query was using for running the statement. The query does not contain hints, therefore the paralllel execution comes from any of those options. I would ask again the DBA for the same statement but with more information

Comment: `select * from dbms_xplan(display_cursor('yoursqlid', format=> 'ALL ALLSTATS LAST'));`

Comment: but again, you have a really good plan with hash value 1802041601. Create a baseline for this plan and you will be sure the statement will run always that way

Comment: Thanks again. If we create a baseline, does it invalidate the collection of statistics by Oracle, and its inner optimizations/adjustment? I mean, if the baseline is run, and the plan will always be the same, Oracle cannot update it by the statistics collected. Will that be a problem? The degree is 8, DBA think it's low and can be higher, I don't know. `select owner,table_name,degree from DBA_TABLES t where t.TABLE_NAME= 'ITEM_HISTORY' and owner = 'MY_APP';`

Comment: so the tables have parallel. For what I see in the plans, the ones with parallel are worse than the ones without it. But I can't be certain without much more data. That is the reason why the statement was executed in parallel, because the table has degree 8. Ask the dba for the SQL Monitoring of those statements to check the elapsed time of each of those plans. He should have this information. Baselines can evolve, so it is not a problem. but in your case the main question now is whether you have to run in parallel or not.

Comment: `containers_parallel_degree` is `CPU`, and `parallel_degree_policy` is `MANUAL`, I think it is fine. Your `display_cursor` query gives DBA `invalid identifier`, maybe because prod uses older version and does not support it? I thought production uses 12g, but I may be wrong; I will check with them again.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fBk8dkBM, query result of `SELECT * FROM table (
   DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('3mg82nwbjdv30', NULL, 'ALLSTATS LAST');`, as the original form does not work. Expiration 1 day. Seems that the bad plan is no longer in cache.

Comment: I think the query took 54s in total.